# Discord Node.js | Adding time onto a timestamp in an embed (v12)

Tags: node.js, discord, timestamp, discord.js, embed

I had a question, so I know to add a timestamp to a `New Discord.MessageEmbed()` you would use `.setTimestamp()`, however, I was wondering how I would go about adding x amount of time to that timestamp, i.e. if my args[1] was "12hr" (12 hours), how would I make the timestamp display a time 12 hours ahead of whoever is viewing the message?

Basically, I'm creating a giveaway-type bot, for personal use, and I'd like the footer to display the end date.

Discord Node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have `let timeAdded = 12h;`. There is [`ms`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms) package for translating that to time in milliseconds.

Also, note that [`.setTimestamp()`](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setTimestamp) method has optional parameter `timestamp`, that defaults to `Date.now()`.

If you connect all this information, you'll get:

```
const ms = require('ms');
let timeAdded = '12h';
const NewEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTimestamp(Date.now() + ms(timeAdded));
```

And that's it! Of course `timeAdded` will have to come from your `args` string, or in some way be fetched from the message, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Discord.js [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setTimestamp), the function `.setTimestamp()` can take an optional input, with the default input being `Date.now()` if left blank.

We can parse your `args[1]` for seconds, minutes, hours, etc. and add them to a date object, then use that object for the `.setTimestamp()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You achieve it this way:

```js
.setTimeStamp() + (<hours you want to add> * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

its not very pretty but it's a quick solution.

##### Alternatively

you can create a new [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and pass it as `parameter` to the [`.setTimeStamp()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setTimestamp) function, because it can take an alternative `parameter`